# Почему съезжает блок меню?

Tags: html, css

Меню состоит из двух блоков `header__left` и `header__right`, они должны находиться в одной линии, Но блок `header_right` съезжает вниз. Как можно это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="layout__header">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header__inner container">
                <div class="header__left">
                    <a class="logo" data-menuanchor="intro" href="#intro">
                        <img class="logo__img" src="./img/logo.png" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="lang-wrap">
                        <input id="lang" type='checkbox'>
                        <label for="lang" class="rus">RUS</label><label for="lang" class="eng">ENG</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="header__right">

                    <button class="header-bars" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <div class="header-bars__line header-bars__line_top"></div>
                        <div class="header-bars__line header-bars__line_middle"></div>
                        <div class="header-bars__line header-bars__line_bottom"></div>
                    </button>
                    <div class="header-menu">
                        <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="what-we-do" href="#whatWeDo" id="whatWeDo_2">
                            <div class="box_1"></div><div class="header-menu__text">What  do we do?</div>
                        </a>
                        <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="work-process" href="#workProcess" id="workProcess_2">
                            <div class="header-menu__text">The process of work</div>
                        </a>
                        <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="why-us" href="#whyUs" id="whyUs_2">
                            <div class="header-menu__text">Why should you choose us?</div>
                        </a>
                        <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="prices" href="#Prices" id="Prices_2">
                            <div class="header-menu__text">Price-list</div>
                        </a>
                        <a class="header-menu__link header-menu__link_order" data-menuanchor="order" href="#Order" id="Order_2">
                            <div class="header-menu__text">Make an order</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
  .layout {}
    .layout__header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1000
    }

    .header {
        padding: 15px 0;
        background-color: #0a0a10;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .header {
            padding: 45px 0 0 ;
            background-color: transparent;
        }
    }
    .header__inner {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        height: 35px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .header__inner {
            align-items: stretch;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    }
    .header__left {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .header__left {
            align-items: stretch;
            flex: 0 0 300px;
        }
    }
    .header__right {
        flex-grow: 1;
        display: flex;
    }

    .logo {
        display: block;
    }
    .logo__img {
        width: 121px;
        height: 35px;
    }

    .lang {
    }
    .lang-wrap {
        margin: 0 0 0 38px;
    }
    .lang__btn {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 3px 0 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .lang__btn:hover {
        color: #ffd8ff;
    }
    .lang__btn:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 1px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: #eb7cff;
    }
    .lang__body {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        padding: 8px 5px;
        margin: 8px 0 0 0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
        border-radius: 12px;
        transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    }
    .open .lang__body {
        display: block;
    }
    .lang__item {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 4px 9px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: 300;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    .lang__item:hover {
        color: #ffd8ff;
    }

    .header-bars {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .header-bars {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    .header-bars__line {
        display: block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #fff;
        transition: transform ease-out .3s, opacity ease-out .3s, background-color ease-out .3s;
    }
    .header-bars:hover .header-bars__line,
    .open .header-bars .header-bars__line {
        background-color: #eb7cff;
    }
    .header-bars__line_middle {
        width: 13px;
        margin: 4px 0;
    }
    .open .header-bars .header-bars__line_top {
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(3px, 5px);
    }
    .open .header-bars .header-bars__line_middle {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .open .header-bars .header-bars__line_bottom {
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(3px, -6px);
    }

    @media (max-width: 1279.98px) {
        .header-menu {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            right: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            margin: 15px 0 0;
            padding: 10px 0;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
            z-index: 99;
        }
        .open .header-menu {
            display: block;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .header-menu {
            flex-grow: 1;
            display: flex;
            margin: -10px 0 0;
        }
    }
    .header-menu__link {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .header-menu__link {
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }
        .header-menu__link:first-child {
            padding-left: 0;
        }
        .header-menu__link:last-child {
            padding-right: 0;
        }
        .header-menu__link_order {
            margin-left: auto;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1920px) {
        .header-menu__link {
            padding: 10px 50px;
        }
    }
    .header-menu__link:not(.active):hover,
    .header-menu__link.active {
        color: #ffd8ff;
    }
    .header-menu__text {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 0 0 0px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.2;
    }
    .header-menu__text:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        left: 0;
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: currentColor;
        transition: height .2s ease;
    }
    .header-menu__link.active .header-menu__text:before {
        height: 9px;
    }
```

Comment: `.header { display: flex; }`

Comment: @InDevX Не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внимательно за структурой проследите.. У вас просто `.header_right` идёт после того, как закрывается `.container`

```css
.layout {}
    .layout__header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1000
    }

    .header {
        padding: 15px 0;
        background-color: #0a0a10;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .header {
            padding: 45px 0 0 ;
            background-color: transparent;
        }
    }
    .header__inner {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        height: 35px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .header__inner {
            align-items: stretch;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    }
    .header__left {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .header__left {
            align-items: stretch;
            flex: 0 0 300px;
        }
    }
    .header__right {
        flex-grow: 1;
        display: flex;
    }

    .logo {
        display: block;
    }
    .logo__img {
        width: 121px;
        height: 35px;
    }

    .lang {
    }
    .lang-wrap {
        margin: 0 0 0 38px;
    }
    .lang__btn {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 3px 0 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .lang__btn:hover {
        color: #ffd8ff;
    }
    .lang__btn:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 1px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: #eb7cff;
    }
    .lang__body {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        padding: 8px 5px;
        margin: 8px 0 0 0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
        border-radius: 12px;
        transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    }
    .open .lang__body {
        display: block;
    }
    .lang__item {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 4px 9px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: 300;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    .lang__item:hover {
        color: #ffd8ff;
    }

    .header-bars {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .header-bars {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    .header-bars__line {
        display: block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #fff;
        transition: transform ease-out .3s, opacity ease-out .3s, background-color ease-out .3s;
    }
    .header-bars:hover .header-bars__line,
    .open .header-bars .header-bars__line {
        background-color: #eb7cff;
    }
    .header-bars__line_middle {
        width: 13px;
        margin: 4px 0;
    }
    .open .header-bars .header-bars__line_top {
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(3px, 5px);
    }
    .open .header-bars .header-bars__line_middle {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .open .header-bars .header-bars__line_bottom {
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(3px, -6px);
    }

    @media (max-width: 1279.98px) {
        .header-menu {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            right: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            margin: 15px 0 0;
            padding: 10px 0;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
            z-index: 99;
        }
        .open .header-menu {
            display: block;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .header-menu {
            flex-grow: 1;
            display: flex;
            margin: -10px 0 0;
        }
    }
    .header-menu__link {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    @media (min-width: 1280px) {
        .header-menu__link {
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }
        .header-menu__link:first-child {
            padding-left: 0;
        }
        .header-menu__link:last-child {
            padding-right: 0;
        }
        .header-menu__link_order {
            margin-left: auto;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1920px) {
        .header-menu__link {
            padding: 10px 50px;
        }
    }
    .header-menu__link:not(.active):hover,
    .header-menu__link.active {
        color: #ffd8ff;
    }
    .header-menu__text {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 0 0 0px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.2;
    }
    .header-menu__text:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        left: 0;
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: currentColor;
        transition: height .2s ease;
    }
    .header-menu__link.active .header-menu__text:before {
        height: 9px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="layout">
    <div class="layout__header">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header__inner container">
                <div class="header__left">
                    <a class="logo" data-menuanchor="intro" href="#intro">
                        <img class="logo__img" src="./img/logo.png" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="lang-wrap">
                        <input id="lang" type='checkbox'>
                        <label for="lang" class="rus">RUS</label><label for="lang" class="eng">ENG</label>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="header__right">

                    <button class="header-bars" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <div class="header-bars__line header-bars__line_top"></div>
                        <div class="header-bars__line header-bars__line_middle"></div>
                        <div class="header-bars__line header-bars__line_bottom"></div>
                    </button>
                    <div class="header-menu">
                        <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="what-we-do" href="#whatWeDo" id="whatWeDo_2">
                            <div class="box_1"></div><div class="header-menu__text">What  do we do?</div>
                        </a>
                        <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="work-process" href="#workProcess" id="workProcess_2">
                            <div class="header-menu__text">The process of work</div>
                        </a>
                        <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="why-us" href="#whyUs" id="whyUs_2">
                            <div class="header-menu__text">Why should you choose us?</div>
                        </a>
                        <a class="header-menu__link" data-menuanchor="prices" href="#Prices" id="Prices_2">
                            <div class="header-menu__text">Price-list</div>
                        </a>
                        <a class="header-menu__link header-menu__link_order" data-menuanchor="order" href="#Order" id="Order_2">
                            <div class="header-menu__text">Make an order</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```